# Post request with http/net results in EOF? Ruby http library

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a post request which works on postman:

[image]

The above works and when I check the list of transactions, it appears.

However, this post request does not work when using Ruby's `http/net` library. What gives?

```
 def post(path, params)
    18:   url = URI.parse('http://www.jobcoin.company.com' + path)
 => 19:   binding.pry
    20:   http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    21:   req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.request_uri)
    22:   req.set_form_data(params)
    23:
    24:   binding.pry
    25:   response = http.request(req)
    26: end

[1] pry(#<JobcoinClient::Requests::Connection>)> url
=> #<URI::HTTP:0x007fb4e622ec80 URL:http://www.jobcoin.company.com/protozoan/api/transactions>
```

Here is what happens:

```
http.request(req)
=> EOFError: end of file reached
```

Comment: I had this exact error working with HTTP a couple weeks ago.  I nearly punched a hole in the wall.  Unfortunately Net::HTTP will sometimes (frequently) give you this `EOFError` for a lot of different reasons without explaining.

Comment: And did you get a solution?

Comment: I will post an answer with some thoughts

Comment: Anyone else know what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Net::HTTP will give you that EOFError for a number of reasons you might not expect, many of which are actually legit (i.e., descriptive).  I find this to be annoying and difficult to debug.  If you Google "ruby net http eoferror" you get tons of SO questions with lots of variety.  When I tried out your code, I also received the EOFError, but when I inspected the response object, I noticed that the request was actually still performed (got a 404 error in my case).

Generally, I use [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) because it's not as low-level as Net::HTTP and is generally easier to use.

Here is an example of your code rewritten to use HTTParty:

```ruby
def post(path, params)
  url = URI.parse('http://www.jobcoin.company.com' + path)

  response = HTTParty.post(url, params)
end
```